# Is there a ADB command to know the timestamp when the home page load of an app is complete?

Tags: android, adb, performance-testing, logcat, launching-application

I want to measure the time taken for any app to completely launch its landing page, with all the necessary UI resources are loaded and displayed. This is different from the [Displayed metric](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time) which captures the time taken to draw the application on screen.

I am curious to understand if Android can track the time stamp when the UI of the app becomes actually usable by the user, which would include the time to load some/all of the UI resources on the landing page